# Primefaces 5 selectOneMenu incorrectly rendering inside tabView

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a selectOne menu inside a PF tabView:

```
<ui:composition template="./../../../ClientSimple.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="top">
            <h2>Public Cloud Menu</h2>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="treelist">
                <p:tabView>
                    <p:tab id="dattab" title="Data">
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="datmen" value="#{clientDataBean.marketid}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{marketbean.allMarksNorm}" var="mark"
                                           itemLabel="#{mark.marketname}"
                                           itemValue="#{mark.marketid}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>                
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

The view is totally distorted with the top part of the menu appearing at the top of the page and the rest of the menu appearing at the bottom.

**If I change to *h:selectOneMenu* everything renders perfectly, but I'd prefer to use the PF component.**  The template page is:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/paceradar.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="/css/paceradar.css"/>
    <h:outputScript name="/js/pace.js"/>

    <h:form>
        <title>Client Module</title>
        <p:panel style="text-align: right;">
            <p:commandLink value="#{secBean.username}" style="margin-left: 10px;" 
                           action="#{secBean.showProfiles}"
                           rendered="#{secBean.showUser}"
                           />
            <p:spacer width="40"/>
            <p:commandLink id="loginbutt" value="Login" action="#{secBean.loginForm}" 
                           process="loginbutt"
                           rendered="#{secBean.login}"/>
            <p:commandLink id="logout" value="Logout" action="#{secBean.logout}"
                           process="logout"
                           rendered="#{secBean.showUser}"/>
        </p:panel>
        <h:link outcome="/EnliteWelcome.xhtml">
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/logo.png" />
        </h:link>
    </h:form>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div id="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem in current latest PF5 version (I just copypasted your XHTML snippet into a templateless test file in a completely blank project with everything set to defaults and most recent versions). So cause is not visible in information provided so far. Post MCVE. Read if necessary http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info if you have no idea how.

Comment: I updated the code which is hopefully MCVE flavor

Comment: Are you implying that you also couldn't reproduce it yourself in a templateless test file in a completely blank project with everything set to defaults and most recent versions? And thus at least one of the things in the template is causing it?

Comment: Yes I am although I have to do more tests as this was previously rendering in the same document (and same template) so while the template could be the cause I can't say for sure yet. I was hoping to get any tips about what I might be doing wrong in my code

Comment: Get the smallest possible code snippet to run. If it works, simply deduct the original code snippet step by step towards the smallest possible working snippet. Once it starts working, then the removed piece was most likely the root culprit of the initial problem. If you don't understand why that piece causes/behaves like that, then that would finally be a good Stack Overflow question. We are generally not interested in "Help, I can't debug, do it for me!" questions and they either get closed as Too Broad or even get ignored.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I just thought MVCE was the smallest possible working code to alow the potential answerer to also experience the debugging process but of course it makes more sense for the questioner to post after exhaustive debugging. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason, removing the panel tag in the template page solves the problem. I couldn't find any css conflicts from inspecting the page. I first thought that the panel could be overflowing and messing up the margins. I modified the 'overflow', setting it to hidden and trying different settings but this didn't solve anything. The problem is solved but I don't understand why the panel is the culprit.

```
    <h:form>
    <title>Client Module</title>

        <p:commandLink value="#{secBean.username}" style="margin-left: 10px;" 
                       action="#{secBean.showProfiles}"
                       rendered="#{secBean.showUser}"
                       />
        <p:spacer width="40"/>
        <p:commandLink id="loginbutt" value="Login" action="#{secBean.loginForm}" 
                       process="loginbutt"
                       rendered="#{secBean.login}"/>
        <p:commandLink id="logout" value="Logout" action="#{secBean.logout}"
                       process="logout"
                       rendered="#{secBean.showUser}"/>

    <h:link outcome="/EnliteWelcome.xhtml">
        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/logo.png" />
    </h:link>
</h:form>
```